# Flex children not expanding to full height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a dynamic footer on my page and I expect the content above it to scale to reach the top of the footer, that's fine and all, but I'm having a problem:

```css
#snippet-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: blue;
}

#content .test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#footer {
  flex: 0 1 10vh;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="snippet-container">
  <div id="page">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would expect the `.test` element to fill the `#content` element, hence the `100%/100% width/height` however it does not.

You can see this reflected as I gave the `.test` element a red border in the snippet.

Comment: are you trying to fill everything with yellow without red right?

Comment: http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Try replacing `flex-fow` with `flex-direction`. That might be the problem, although I am not sure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Problem

The problem is that your `#page` flex container is not *reaching* the `.test` element since `.test` is not a child, it is a descendant of the flex item.

> The contents of a flex container consists of zero or more flex items:
> each child of a flex container becomes a flex item.

Each flex item is affected by the flex container, but the flex item's descendants are not.

#### Solution

You need to add `display: flex` to your `#content` as well.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwx1k3b3/)**

#### Code snippet

```css
#snippet-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}
#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
#content .test {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#footer {
  flex: 0 1 10vh;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="snippet-container">
  <div id="page">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works only for the direct flex child, but if the item you need to have 100% is wrapped in more div elements then each of them needs height:100%, https://jsfiddle.net/mwx1k3b3/398/

Answer (score 9):

This does it for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/wjr0wwht/2/

In order to make the 'test' div grow to full height, you need to make content also a `display: flex` like this:

```css
#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And then make the test itself grow:

```css
#content .test {
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```